# From SQLite db select one layer and create a shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, export, sqlite

I have a SQLite database with multiple tables.
I just want at the end to create a shapefile with one of the layer/table (called msm_Catchment) that I have in my SQLite.

I want to run the Python script outside of QGIS editor (from the command line).

This would be the starting of my code...
I think my first issue is to select the layer I want in the SQLite.

```
import os # This is is needed in the pyqgis console also
from qgis.core import (QgsVectorLayer)


# get the path to the shapefile e.g. /home/project/data/ports.shp
path_to_sqlite = r"C:\DHI\42802016\LISA_Base.sqlite"
# The format is:

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(path_to_ports_layer, "msm_Catchment", "ogr")
if not vlayer.isValid():
    print("Layer failed to load!")

# I think I don't need the following ? it is only to open and see it in QGIS?
#vlayer = iface.addVectorLayer(path_to_ports_layer, "msm_Catchment", "ogr")
#if not vlayer:
#    print("Layer failed to load!")

    
_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(vlayer,"C:\DHI\42802016\msm_Catchment.shp","utf-8",None,"ESRI Shapefile")
```

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is exactly? Do you get an error that you can post here?
Creating the vector layer should work the way you try it.

Comment: Hi @Kasluk24, there is no error yet because the code is not complete. The first thing I want to do and I don't know how is to have a python script that I ran from the command which will read one of the table in my SQLite database. There are multiple table in the SQlite and I want to focus on only one which is called "msm_Catchment". From this one I just want to create a new shapefile externally to my SQLite db. So it would be the second task of my python code to export as SHP.

Answer (score 1):

Alright. The script should be something like this.

For a standalone application, you must first initialise the QGIS application:

```
from qgis.core import QgsApplication
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r"C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis", True) # Path to the QGIS installation
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()
```

Also see here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#using-pyqgis-in-standalone-scripts

Then you can create the vector layer as you have done it and write it to a shapefile:

```
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsVectorFileWriter
path_to_sqlite = r"C:\DHI\42802016\LISA_Base.sqlite"

vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(path_to_sqlite + "|layername=msm_Catchment", "msm_Catchment", "ogr") # Create QgsVectorLayer from the Layer msm_Catchment from the SQLite database
if not vlayer.isValid():
    print("Layer failed to load!")
else:
    writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(vlayer, r"C:\DHI\42802016\msm_Catchment.shp", "utf-8", driverName="ESRI Shapefile") # Write the QgsVectorLayer to the shapefile
```

For more information about `QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat`, see here: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Vector/QgsVectorFileWriter.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat

At the end of the script there should be the following line to exit the QGIS application:

```
qgs.exitQgis()
```

The simplest way to execute the script is to open the command prompt and navigate to your python script. Use the command: `call "C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\python-qgis.bat"` (or similar) to open the python console with the environment pre-configrued. Execute the script by importing it `import filename.py`

Comment: thank you Kasluk24, the script is creating a msm_Catchment shp, however when I open it it is not the correct table that it had copied. It is taking a table which is called msm_Node. And this msm_Node has a geometry 'Point'. My msm_Catchment table has a geometry 'Polygon'. So I don't know if it is by default creating a point shapefile so it takes the first table which have a point geometry; or if it doesn't find my msm_catchment table for any reason

Comment: Oh sorry, that's my mistake. I forgot `|layername=msm_Catchment` in the URI. I have now corrected my answer.

Comment: Hello @Kasluk24, would you be able to help me with this one? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/403698/creating-features-from-existing-point-layer-in-standalone-pyqgis-script