# Creating features from existing point layer in Standalone PyQGIS script

Tags: qgis, python, sqlite, standalone, add-feature

I am trying to add a feature into an existing layer in my SQLite database.
The script below is working:

```py
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('msm_LoadPoint')
layer = QgsVectorLayer(layers[0].dataProvider().dataSourceUri(),'','ogr')
caps = layer.dataProvider().capabilities()

if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.AddFeatures:
    feat = QgsFeature(layer.fields())
    feat.setAttributes([1,'test'])
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(510620,5453185)))
    res, outfeats = layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([feat])
```

However I would like to run this as standalone, I workout this following code but there is still something wrong at line 17 when calling for `QgsVectorLayer` and inserting row. The error said:

> 'GqsVecorLayer', object does not support indexing

though it was working when running in QGIS.

```py
import os # This is is needed in the pyqgis console also
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error
from qgis.core import QgsApplication

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.18\apps\qgis", True) # Path to the QGIS installation
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

#Open the vector layer and write the new feature in the msm_LoadPoint layer:

from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsVectorFileWriter

path_to_sqlite = r"C:\dhi\42802016\LISA\Tool_Test_Loadpoints\Test_run\Lisa_Base.sqlite"

layers = QgsVectorLayer(path_to_sqlite+ "|layername=msm_LoadPoint", "msm_LoadPoint", "ogr")
#layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('msm_LoadPoint')
layer = QgsVectorLayer(layers[0].dataProvider().dataSourceUri(),'','ogr') #line 17
caps = layer.dataProvider().capabilities()

if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.AddFeatures:
    feat = QgsFeature(layer.fields())
    feat.setAttributes([1,'test'])
    feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(510620,5453185)))
    res, outfeats = layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([feat])

qgs.exitQgis()
```

Comment: If `layers = QgsVectorLayer(...)` in line 15, why do you use it as a list in line 17? (`layers[0]...`)

Comment: in line 15 I am trying to give him the path to open and select the correct layer. Then in line 17 I am trying to insert the row 0 in the layer

Comment: See the PyQGIS CookBook to read how to set a layer URI for a SpatiaLite layers: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#vector-layers

Comment: Thank you I read it but couldn't find a way to make my code work. I tried to change the line ```#layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('msm_LoadPoint')```  by ```QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layers)''' but still. In the explanation you sent , they insert a new entire shp in the SQlite, I want to fill an existing layer

Answer (score 0):

Line 17 is not needed at all. You do not have to / cannot add an empty row to the layer first. With your line 15 you get the desired vector layer.

The minimal required code could look like this:

```
from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsVectorDataProvider, QgsVectorLayer, QgsVectorFileWriter, QgsFeature, QgsGeometry, QgsPointXY

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.18\apps\qgis", True) # Path to the QGIS installation
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

path_to_sqlite = r"C:\dhi\42802016\LISA\Tool_Test_Loadpoints\Test_run\Lisa_Base.sqlite"

# Open the vector layer and write the new feature in the msm_LoadPoint layer:
layer = QgsVectorLayer(path_to_sqlite + "|layername=msm_LoadPoint", "msm_LoadPoint", "ogr")
if not layer.isValid():
    print('Layer not valid')
else:
    caps = layer.dataProvider().capabilities()
    if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.AddFeatures:
        feat = QgsFeature(layer.fields())
        feat.setAttributes([1,'test'])
        feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(510620,5453185)))
        (res, outfeats) = layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([feat])

qgs.exitQgis()
```